# Flutter / Flame - How to work with PanDetector and other GestureDetector for Components at same time?

Tags: flutter, flame

My game uses PanDetector to move the player.

```
class MyGame extends BaseGame with PanDetector, HasTapableComponents {


  @override
  void onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {

    // move the player
   player.move(details.delta.dx, details.delta.dy);

    super.onPanUpdate(details);
  }


}
```

I needed to add a pause button on the top-right of the screen.

```
class PauseComponent extends PositionComponent with Tapable, HasGameRef<MyGame>{

  Rect rect;
  Sprite spritePause = Sprite("pause_button.png");

  PauseComponent(){

    rect = Rect.fromLTWH(
        Get.find<Config>().screenSize.width * 0.92,
        Get.find<Config>().screenSize.height * 0.04,
        Get.find<Config>().screenSize.width * 0.05,
        Get.find<Config>().screenSize.height * 0.10);

  }

  @override
  void render(Canvas c) {

    spritePause.renderRect(c, rect);

  }

  @override
  void onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {

    if(gameRef.gameState == GameState.PLAYING){

      gameRef.gameState = GameState.PAUSED;
      gameRef.pauseEngine();

    } else {

      gameRef.gameState = GameState.PLAYING;
      gameRef.resumeEngine();

    }

    print("STATUS: ${gameRef.gameState}");

    super.onTapDown(details);
  }
}
```

But it's not working, how can I make the PauseComponent's onTapDown work, use PanDetector and some other Detector to the PauseComponent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used addWidgetsOverlay mixin and added a Pause Button custom widget since PanDetector was not working with Tapable.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PauseButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
          onPressed: (){
            print("TOUCH!");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And removing HasTapableComponents mixin (not sure if it was conflicting with anything), now it's working.

```
class MyGame extends BaseGame with HasWidgetsOverlay, PanDetector {

  MyGame(){

  addWidgetsOverlay("Pause Button", PauseButton());


 }

}
```

Comment: Now you are simply using the original flutter way of doing it, which is fine, but not what was in you original question.

Comment: Sorry, I edit my answer, I ended up using addWidgetsOverlay, since it's easier to add a Widget and it's function than creating a new Component.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `HasTapableComponents` on `MyGame`, and you also have to add your `PauseComponent` to `MyGame` (but you might just have omitted that part of the code).

```
class MyGame extends BaseGame with PanDetector, HasTapableComponents {
  ....
}
```

You can read more about tapable components [here](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/master/doc/input.md#tapable-components).

Comment: I already added HasTapableComponents mixin and added the Component to MyGame.